# XML Path needed

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I need to write a XML path that returns a book published after 2003, category is children and I just need to display the author and title of the book?  What is frustrating is that I have everything in the XPATH that wrote except I am missing the author.

Comment: Here is my Xpath: /bookstore/book/title/author|/bookstore/book[@category="CHILDREN"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` expression:

```
/bookstore/book[@category="CHILDREN" and year>2003]/*[name()="author" or name()="title"]
```

Here we select every book with the `category` attribute equaling to `CHILDREN` and with `year` node value more than `2003`. `*[name()="author" or name()="title"]` helps to select only specific children: `author` and `title`.

Demo using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) tool:

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath '/bookstore/book[@category="CHILDREN" and year > 2003]/*[name()="author" or name()="title"]'
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
```

If you want to see the values of `author` and `title` nodes, add `/text()` to the end of xpath expression:

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath '/bookstore/book[@category="CHILDREN" and year > 2003]/*[name()="author" or name()="title"]/text()'
Harry Potter
J K. Rowling
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had tried something similar however it I just did name() and that's it.  I tried it and it works.  Thanks again. I spent all week/hours on this so I am glad I found this site :)

Comment: Question that I have, I would have to use functions otherwise I would not get the results right?  Just trying to see if there was an easier way of getting the same output.

Comment: Bummer, I would have given you a 5 I didn't see it until after I hit the checkmark.  This answer is definitely a 5.